# How can I make a textbox readonly/disable for users and not for the admin (PHP)?

Tags: php, textarea, readonly

I'm trying this stuff but all I found is TinyMCE codes. Can you help me in here? I'm creating a system with tables(input type="text").. Where I can put my daily allowance for monday-friday's. I want that only me can put numbers on that textarea.. When other users logged in, the textarea is disabled/not editable.. How can I start with the coding? I start studying php yesterday :)

Comment: i wouldn't even show it, disabling it confuses some people

Comment: Hm.. What if the users only want to see my allowance for this week? I want to make it not editable so they can only check my allowance. Do you have any advice or alternative? :)

Comment: form input fields are designed for, well, input, when you start messing with such basics it can really mess people up. display the editable form inputs to you, and just echo the text for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in this kind of case, you'll want to display input fields to your admin :

```
<input type="text" name="..." id="..." value="..." />
```

And you'll only display values to the other users -- no input fields, as they don't have to do any input.

I suppose you have some way of testing if a user is an admin, either using a database, or a session ?

If so, depending on the kind of user, you'll use an if statement, to either display the input, or the value :

```
// $isAdmin has to be set accordingly
if ($isAdmin) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="..." id="..." value="..." />';
} else {
    echo "the value";
}
```

After that, of course, on form's submission, you'll do the same test, to only work with `$_POST` if the form has been submitted by an admin.

Comment: Very noice! :) I'll try this now. :) Thanks Pascal Martin :>

Comment: I recommend this methodology.  No sense making an input when no input is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I too like the idea pointed out by Pascal MARTIN and  Phoenix....

But still if are looking for disabling the textbox or textarea we have two options for it...

1) disabled="disabled" add these option to the required textarea or text field

2) readonly="readonly"

where  option 1 only allows user to view the content....

option 2 allows users to view the content as well as copy it ....but cannot modify it.................

Comment: Option 1 is what I'm into. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are not logged in, and if so, add `disabled="disabled"` to the `input` and throw any POSTs that attempt to update data.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to hide the text area is with the black-overlay class. Create a div just below the text area and assign this. You may control the opacity and cursor as well as the area. Nothing is fool proof, but with min opacity, they will not know it is there. It is always possible to change the screen size to move the area if scrollable. but it works.

```
.textarea_overlay {
    display: block; 
    position: fixed; 
    margin-top: -??;    
    width: ??;  
    height: ??; 
    background-color: black; 
    z-index:1001;   
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;  
    opacity:.01; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);  
    cursor: not-allowed; 
}
```